# Linear-gradient to produce dashed lines

Tags: css

I have a linear gradient in my page and it's [Dashed line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oTUw.png)

[image]

Actually, it is suppose to be a solid line, not dashed. This is the code for it:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient( left top, #ffe1d9  50%, #989cdb 50%); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #ffe1d9  50%, #989cdb 50%); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #ffe1d9  50%, #989cdb 50%); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #ffe1d9  50%, #989cdb 50%); /* Standard syntax */
```

Anyone would know how to produce a solid linear gradient? Thank you!

Comment: I'm unsure if this is possible without a precomputed image or non-css trickery. I'd be interested to see if it is plausible, but a few google searches seems to point to non-plausible.

Comment: What you're seeing is the edge between `#ffe1d9` and `#989cdb`.  It's not a dashed line; it's just a lack of smoothing inherent with CSS gradients with a solid stop.

Comment: Hm.. Interesting. Is there a way to see just the line between the two?

Comment: There is no line between the two, just pixels of one color clashing with another, creating a visible "edge". What your picture shows also isn't a "dashed line", but [Jaggies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaggies).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the browser thinks that it doesn't have to do any anti-aliasing for this gradient, since there is a sharp cutoff point between the colors. So, no gradient effect!
(The effect isn't the same in all browsers, by the way; Chrome seems to suffer the most.)

Solution: don't use 50% for both color breaks, but leave just the smallest amount between them, to create a actual gradient from color to color. Half a percent will do.

```css
.lines {
  height: 4em;
  
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #ffe1d9 49.75%, #989cdb 50.25%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #ffe1d9 49.75%, #989cdb 50.25%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #ffe1d9 49.75%, #989cdb 50.25%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #ffe1d9 49.75%, #989cdb 50.25%);
}
```

```html
<div class="lines"></div>
```

For comparison, here is the original with 50% each.

```css
.lines {
  height: 4em;
  
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #ffe1d9 50%, #989cdb 50%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #ffe1d9 50%, #989cdb 50%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #ffe1d9 50%, #989cdb 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #ffe1d9 50%, #989cdb 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="lines"></div>
```

Comment: It's not perfectly clean, but probably as close as you can get. For Firefox, 1% difference seems to be a more precise result, though!

Comment: @TheThirdMan At 1% difference, there's already a noticeable fuzziness between the two halves on my screen. Not sure if the OP would like that.

Comment: +1, thanks! In Chrome 63, using 49.99% and 50% (for a `to right` and `to left` gradient) worked for me (and it still looked like a hard edge).